# Is data from Hard disk with damaged PCB recoverable?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

Is it possible to recover data from a hard disk with a damaged PCB?

The BIOS ROM chip is also possibly physically damaged.

Trying simply swapping PCB did not work, but showed bad disk. LBA IO errors or something of that nature.

Comment: HDDs do not have a *"BIOS ROM"* chip.  You're just guessing as to the identify/function of a chip.  How did you even manage to damage any chip(s) since a photo of a Seagate ST1000DM010 shows no exposed components on the PCB?

Comment: FYI I've noticed that marketing blurbs for tablets and smart phones misuse the technical term ROM, which is supposed to mean Read-Only Memory.  Real ROM has its contents programed at time of silicon masking, and can never be changed.  The term "ROM" is misused to refer to NAND flash dedicated to (writable) storage of the firmware  and user data, in contrast to the RAM (for execution of programs).  Apparently marketing likes the alliteration and/or symmetry of RAM and ROM acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but by a data recovery expert who can take the platters out in a lab environment. Not by a general end user.

Comment: thanks. but what about the ROM data? Is it also required to be recovered?

Comment: I suspect the 3rd party will put the platters into some enclosure which has its own ROM. The ROM, in this case, is just a controller for the physical device. It won't have any of your data stored within it.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. If you’re lucky, this can be accomplished by swapping out the PCB with another that is compatible. Data recovery professionals usually have a stock of these PCBs. It shouldn’t be too expensive either.

However, if it’s not possible to procure a compatible PCB, the data will have to recovered directly from the platters, which is risky and will be quite expensive.

The ROM only contains some parts of the firmware. Most of the firmware is stored on the platters itself, including all the data required to read the platters.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please write more specifically on the hard disk Seagate ST1000DM010?

Comment: I don’t see how I could make this any more specific. You’ll have to be more specific if you want additional information.

Comment: thanks again, i meant if any information is available regarding the bios ROM of that specific hdd,

Comment: *"Most of the firmware is stored on the platters itself, including all the data required to read the platters."* -- Seems like you made that up, as that creates a chicken-egg problem.

Comment: But does seagate keep a copy of that BIOS for every HDD at least for the warranty period (or sometime)?

Comment: @sawdust No, why? [Check this](https://www.datalab247.com/articles/article6.html). The "boot" process is simple. // A copy of the specific stage 1 firmware itself is not enough. A PCB is required. It will contain the firmware anyway.

Comment: Okay, some of my knowledge was dated, but from similar articles learned how manufacturers are cutting costs.  But you're still blending your misstatements with the facts.  *"The "boot" process is simple"*  -- Where does that "info" come from?  I've written disk firmware as well as worked on booting SoCs.  So I don't agree with that claim of yours.  BTW beware of articles that use PC terminology to simplify the explanation of embedded systems.